# How to configure Struts 2.3 to accept both GET and POST parameters?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, http-post, url-parameters

We have migrated from 2.0 to 2.3. In Struts 2.0, we were able to send an AJAX request that contained both post and get parameters. But after migrating to Struts 2.3, were are not able to do such requests.

Here is what a sample AJAX request made using Prototype.js looks like :

```
var url = '/security/userdetails.action?mode=edit&userid=5';
var params = Form.serialize(form);
new Ajax.Request(url,
        {
            parameters: params,
            onSuccess: function(trans) {
                console.debug('success', trans);
            },
            onFailure: function(trans) {
                console.debug('failure', trans);
            },
            onException:function(trans) {
                console.debug('exception', trans);
            }
        });
```

As you can see, the above AJAX request contains both GET and POST requests. This worked fine with 2.0 but in 2.3, it seems the request is validated and the request is forwarded to result type "input", but for that we have no JSP configured, and in the end all we get is a 404 Not Found Error.

But if we change the code to the following, it works in Struts 2.3 as well

```
var url = '/security/userdetails.action?mode=edit';    // ------ The Changes are here
var params = Form.serialize(form);
params.userid = 5;  // ----- And here
new Ajax.Request(url,
        {
            parameters: params,
            onSuccess: function(trans) {
                console.debug('success', trans);
            },
            onFailure: function(trans) {
                console.debug('failure', trans);
            },
            onException:function(trans) {
                console.debug('exception', trans);
            }
        });
```

What is wrong with the first method ? Is there a configuration in Struts 2.3 to allow that request to be made ?

Comment: Try to debug the parameter for which validation fails and you get input result. There  is very less likely chance that this is because of Struts 2.3 configuration.

Comment: @Yogi If i use only the url, '/security/userdetails.action?mode=edit&userid=5' and do not include post parameters, it works. Both of them (get and post) seperately work. But together as one, they dont. BTW is there any way to get what validation message is set to the input result type ?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off; the Ajax request doesn't "contain both GET and POST requests", it contains parameters in the URL and in the request body. I'm not sure what change would affect this, but the dispatch process between S2.0 and S2.3 changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is this :

The **userid** was defined as an integer in the action class, so obviously the setter and getter for that was defined in terms of integer as well

But this userid, was present in both the url (as the query string) and in the post body - so basically an array of two strings. when the struts tries to parse the integer from the array, it gets the numberformatexception -> this results in invalid form submission and thus redirects to the "input" result type.

I did not see the struts log in that matter and got swayed away from the actual problem.

Thanks for your inputs though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) works and which method Struts2 uses to retrieve parameters from the request, and method GET/POST (not both) used during that. Struts2 uses [`request.getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) to get parameters

> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

but you are using http post method and parameters should be post data.

Comment: If I use struts 2.0 jars instead of struts 2.3's, it works fine.

Comment: So I should only use either POST or GET, but not both ? What i do not understand is '/security/userdetails.action?mode=edit' - GET along with POST parameters work, but '/security/userdetails.action?mode=edit&userid=5' - GET along with POST does not work. How is it different ? There is only a parameter added right.

Comment: If you are using GET method you should use parameters in the url or use POST then you use form data, if you using url with parameters while using POST, then you should get that parameters from the url. Do you understand? You can't use GET and POST method simultaneously.